# CakePHP 3 json response Datetime formatting

Tags: json, datetime, cakephp-3.x

I'm looking for an easy way, so that all Type Datetime fields in a json response get converted to a format I like to have them. Basically I'm looking for something like `Time::setToStringFormat('dd.MM.YYYY');` or something else, which would prevent me from doing it manually in each response, as I would like to have the same dateformat for all datetime fields in my app.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Shame on me for not reading: http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.I18n.DateFormatTrait.html#_setJsonEncodeFormat

The answer is `Time::setJsonEncodeFormat()`

Comment: And you have to put it in `config/bootstrap.php`. In addiction you can configure other time classes like `FrozenTime`, `Date` and `FrozenDate` by using the same method.